# Execution findbugs of goal org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.5:findbugs failed: Java returned: 1

Tags: java, maven, java-11, findbugs, openjdk-11

Findbugs does not support jdk11, I have a project in which I have a dependency jar which uses findbugs.

https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/issues/93

Although I don't have findbugs maven plugin in my project but due to the dependency jar, it still executes.

How can I stop it from executing, because it fails every time.

I tried with below, but doesn't work.

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.findbugs-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${project.basedir}/exclude-findbugs.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>findbugs</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Can someone please help me? 
TIA

Comment: That means you have a parent which contains the execution of the findbugs-maven-plugin not a dependency. I strongly recomment to get rid of findbugs-maven-plugin...

Answer (score 2):

It worked by adding a skip tag as true. as below.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.findbugs-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${project.basedir}/exclude-findbugs.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```